# Indexing error while trying to retrieve specific letter

Tags: python

I am an accountant and a beginner to coding. I am trying to understand how indexing works.  I am trying to extract the second letter in a string.

```
def myfuncs(words):
    for chars in words:
        b = chars[1]
        return b
```

When `b = chars[0]` the first letter is being displayed. However when I change the value to any other number, `b = chars[1]` or `b = chars[2]`, I receive an error *"string index out of range"*. What is happening? How is the machine looking at my code?

Comment: What are you passing in as `words`?

Comment: show sample function call which produces the error.  what type is your `words` parameter.  it could be a simple string or a list or a tuple or something else.  how python will execute the code will depend on that.

Comment: If `words` is a string, then `chars` will just be a single character. `chars[1]` tries to get the second character, but there's only 1 character so that gets an error.

Comment: If `words` is a string like `"this is multiple words"`, you probably want to split into into a list of words with `for chars in words.split():`

Comment: Can you provide an example of sample input to `words` variable?

Comment: The behavior will vary depending on whether the `words` argument you pass in is a list/tuple, or a string (or something else). That's why we need you to show us the value of `words` you're passing in, to make this a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will iterate through each character in the 'words' string. hence chars[1] will give an error. For your understanding, let's use enumerate to iterate through 'Words'
let `words = "BLA bla βλα"`

```
def myfuncs(words):
    for i,chars in enumerate(words):
        print(i,chars)

words = "BLA bla βλα"
myfuncs(words)
```

output will be

```
0 B
1 L
2 A
3  
4 b
5 l
6 a
7  
8 β
9 λ
10 α
```

for iterating through each word in words use `words.split()`, which will split the 'words' on whitespace and return a list strings

```
def myfuncs_1(words):
    words=words.split()
    print('words.split() returns:',words)
    for i,chars in enumerate(words):
        print(i,chars)

words = "BLA bla βλα"
myfuncs_1(words)
```

output:

```
words.split() returns: ['BLA', 'bla', 'βλα']
0 BLA
1 bla
2 βλα
```

if you want the second alphabet of only the first string in 'words' use

```
def myfuncs_2(words):    
for i,chars in enumerate(words.split()):
    b = chars[1]
    return b

words = "BLA bla βλα"
print(myfuncs_2(words))
```

which will output `L`

if you want the second alphabet of all the strings in 'words' use:

```
def myfuncs_3(words):
    b=[]
    for i,chars in enumerate(words.split()):
        b.append(chars[1])
    return b

words = "BLA bla βλα"
print(myfuncs_3(words))
```

output will be : `['L', 'l', 'λ']`

Answer (score 1):

If the `words` is a string then `char` will be only one character of that string as the `for` loop is just traversing through the whole string, it is not appending anything to the `char[]`. It is just temporarily storing the current single character of the string in the `char` and as you have only one value in it and the index start from `0`; `char[1]` will be an invalid point as there is no data other than that single character.

Now if you want to store each elements of the string in the `char` then you need to add this line:

```py
char_list =[]
for char in words.split():
    char_list.append(char)

#or

char_list = [ char for char in open('the_textfile.txt').read()]
```

Now you can access the 2nd 4th or nth position ( n is the lenght of the string) of the `char_list`